# Send Email in Django From Gmail Account

Tags: python, django, gmail

In my `settings.py` file I have the following:

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "thatotherbatman@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "supersecretstring"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Then I run `python manage.py shell` And do:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail("foo", "bar", settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ["otheruser@gmail.com"])
```

Which produces this:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I've also enabled less secure apps in my google account. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error means that your DNS server cannot resolve the host name. Check the DNS settings on the machine that you run Djano.

Comment: It was definitely something funky about the state of the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the same error later in the night when trying to do a `pip install`. Rebooted the machine, and the error went away.